# Diagnosing Laptop Screen Issue

Tags: laptop, lcd

A family member's laptop with touch screen suddenly started displaying poorly, as in the attached photo.  (The image should not be displaying duplicated, as it appears.)  Upon close inspection, no physical damage or crack was found.  The laptop is generally very clean and not used in hostile environments.  HDMI out to an external monitor displays without issues.  Wiggling in places like the hinge and around the frame don't appear to make a difference.  Before we replace the screen...

From the photo, is anyone confident that the screen must be cracked, or does this malfunction more likely stem from a bad cable/connection?  I suspect that there must be a crack near the left middle of the screen, because of how the malfunction displays, but looking closely, I really cannot see anything for sure.

[image]

Comment: You should be able to see with the computer off if it is cracked or not. Likely a cable issue. Visit a local shop

Comment: Can you connect to an external monitor, this would rule out a graphics card issue